# LIGO interferometer vs. holographic interferometer, is there a difference?

Tags: classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, interferometry

I understand they are used for different purposes but does anyone know why you couldn't use the LIGO in place of the holographic interferometer ? The Holographic interferometer was used to test for a holographic universe by trying to measure "noise" in the fabric of space time, but since a laser was used I assume it does this by measuring displacement of the laser beams which is essentially what LIGO does to measure the distortion of space as it flexes and relaxes.

By the way the test with the Holometer was done in Fermilab in 2015 by Hogan and the results did not support the holographic theory of the universe. Thank you.  ( I was not sure of what team to ask this. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fermilab holometer consists of two Michelson interferometers (with ~40 meter long arms) sitting right next to each other.  The idea is that there maybe a fundamental jiggling of space-time (not necessarily gravitational waves) that will move the two splitter mirrors in the same direction.  This would then cause a correlated change in the fringe patterns of the two interferometers.  In a Dec 2015 paper [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.01216v1.pdf) the measured correlation function is shown between 0-6 MHz. The data above 1 MHz (above environmental influences) is used to rule out a particular model of Planck scale space-time jiggling.  At some level they must also be able to set a limit on high frequency gravitational waves causing a simultaneous change in output from the two interferometers.

The difference between the LIGO interferometers and the holometer is that the Hanford, Washington and Livingston, Louisiana splitter mirrors are 3000 km apart while the two splitter mirrors at Fermilab are right next to each other.  Also, the LIGO arms are 4000 meters long versus 40 meters for the holometer.

Presumably, the output of the two LIGO interferometers could be cross correlated and study the simultaneous jiggling of splitter mirrors that are 3000 km apart.  Because of the longer arms, LIGO would do the correlation at lower frequencies than Fermilab.  Are there any hypothesized Planck scale fluctuations that might cause simultaneous jiggling in mirrors 3000 km apart?

In fact, LIGO has seen a simultaneous (shifted by 7 msec) change in fringe patterns of the two interferometers (eg: GW150914).  A correlation function (shifted by 7 msec) would show power in the 30-150 Hz region).  LIGO has interpreted this signal as a gravitational wave.